# Dual booting Ubuntu 13.10 and Win 8 on Asus S400CA

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, asus

I recently got my new laptop and right away installed ubuntu 13.10 by mounting \ onto the 24gb SSD cache of my machine while \home onto 150000 Mb of the HDD and swap onto 8gb of the HDD. I installed ubuntu using UEFI (not Legacy, or CSM in my case). I then tried to boot my win 8 but found that it cannot be repaired by the automatic repair program of windows. I installed and ran boot repair in ubuntu but it didn't help. So I ran it again choosing to create a bootinfo summary file. Here it is.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6497647/

Also, I turned off fast boot and secure boot before installing ubuntu, and my disk was in AHCI mode (not Raid).

I would like my Win 8 to dual boot with Ubuntu, together caching in SSD. Or at least, Ubuntu caches in SSD while Windows boots from HDD. I really hope someone can enlighten me.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest would be to wipe the disk(s) and reinstall win8 first and then Ubuntu :)

Comment: So after all, I reinstalled windows on a separate partition, then use bootrepair to repair the grub and everything just worked. Before I followed on of the post on askubuntu.com and overwrote my windows 8 with ubuntu. Using the same method (partitioning before installing), I am now triple-booting win 8.1, ubuntu 13.10 and mint 16 cinnamon, which is amazing.